# Filling ChoiceBox with custom property in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

How can I fill `ChoiceBox` with e.g. a `StringProperty` from my custom class?

I have simply design in SceneBuilder with a `ChoiceBox` and I have a `Person` class with my data.

```
public class Person{
    private final StringProperty firstName;

    public Person(){
        this(null);
    }

    public Person(String fname){
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fname);
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return this.firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fname){
        this.firstName.set(fname);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty(){
        return this.firstName;
    }
}
```

In main class I have:

```
private ObservableList<Person> personList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
this.personList.add(new Person("Human1"));

RootController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setChoiceBox(this);

public ObservableList<Person> getPersonList(){
    return this.personList;
}
```

And in my controller:

```
public class RootController {
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox personBox;

    public RootController(){

    }

    @FXML 
    private void initialize(){

    }

    public void setChoiceBox(App app){

        personBox.setItems(app.getPersonList());
    }


}
```

But this code fill my ChoiceBox by function name(??) or something like that.
How can I fill it with the firstName property?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you've created yourself a big problem by making the `firstName` property mutable here.

AFAIK it's not possible to make `ChoiceBox` listen to modifications of that property (at least not without replacing the `skin`, which would be awfully complicated).

This could be done with a `ComboBox` however.

You just need to use a custom `cellFactory`:

```
private ListCell<Person> createCell(ListView<Person> listView) {
    return new ListCell<Person>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                textProperty().unbind();
                setText("");
            } else {
                textProperty().bind(item.firstNameProperty());
            }
        }

    };
}
```

```
ComboBox<Person> cb = new ComboBox<>(personList);
cb.setCellFactory(this::createCell);
cb.setButtonCell(createCell(null));
...
```

Comment: I'm completely with @fabian but for me the question arises why and when does a persons first name really change? EDIT: Upvote for the hint

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I would suggest to use the 'easiest way'.The **ChoiceBox** uses the `toString()` method of the **Person** class resulting in something like `choiceBox.Person@18f8865`.

By overriding the `toString()` method you can define what the ChoiceBox will display. In your case return the value of the `firstName` property:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName.get();
}
```